# General integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{p}}\ln\tan x \,dx $

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

I was motivated by the integral  $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/12} \ln\tan(x)\,dx$ which was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761440) which is equal to $-\frac{2}{3}G$ where is $G$ is Catalan's constant.
With this motivation I came up with a result

> $$\int_0^{\pi/24}\ln\tan x\,dx=\pi\ln\left(\frac{G\left(\frac{25}{24}\right)G\left(\frac{35}{24}\right)}{G\left(\frac{13}{24}\right)G\left(\frac{23}{24}\right)}\right)-\frac{\pi}{24}\ln\left(\frac{4096\pi^{12}}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\left(2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)^5}\right)$$**Notation:** $G$ denotes [*Barnes G-function*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function).

Since Wolfram cannot generate the closed form however, the closed form obtained as  per the [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi+ln+%28%28BarnesG%5B35%2F24%5D*BarnesG%5B25%2F24%5D%29%2F%28BarnesG%5B23%2F24%5D*BarnesG%5B13%2F24%5D%29%29-pi%2F24+ln%28%282%5E12+pi%5E12%29%2F%28sqrt%282-sqrt+3%29*%282%2Bsqrt%282%2Bsqrt+3%29%29%5E5%29%29) check is found to be correct.

Moreover, I came up with following inequality, the close upper bound of the integral, surprisingly in terms of $ e$ and $G$ which is as follows.

> $$\bigg|\int_0^{\pi/24}\ln\tan x \,dx\bigg|  < \frac{e^{-1}}{G}\cdots (1)$$
> **Notation:** $e$ denotes  *Euler's number*.

Now I'm curious to know,

$\bullet$ *Can we generalize the integral*

> $$\int_0^{\pi/p} \ln \tan x \,dx\, =\text{?} \; \; p\neq  0 $$

$\bullet$ *How to prove  $(1)$ using the inequality theorem*?

Thank you

Comment: See A class of series acceleration formulae for Catalan's constant, David M. Bradley, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0356.pdf

Answer (score 3):

*Just approximations.*

Concerning the integral

$$I(t)=\int_0^t \log (\tan (x))\,dx$$ $$I=\tan ^{-1}(\tan (t)) \log (\tan (t))+\frac{i}{2} (\text{Li}_2(i \tan (t))-\text{Li}_2(-i \tan (t)))$$

Since $t$ is supposed to be small, I should use
$$I(t)=-t (1-\log (t))+\frac {t^2}9 \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{b_i}\, t^{2i-1} $$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 i & a_i & b_i \\
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 7 & 50 \\
 3 & 62 & 2205 \\
 4 & 127 & 18900 \\
 5 & 146 & 81675 \\
 6 & 1414477 & 2766889125 \\
 7 & 32764 & 212837625 \\
 8 & 16931177 & 351486135000 \\
 9 & 11499383114 & 740606614122375 \\
 10 & 91546277357 & 17865510428390625
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using $t=\frac \pi {24}$ this gives as a result
$-0.39681136139214865267218614585540$ while the exact result should be
$-0.39681136139214865267218614585537$

**Edit**

Another possibility is to let $\tan(x)=u$ to make
$$I(t)=\int_0^{\tan ^{-1}(t)} \frac{\log (u)}{u^2+1}\,du= \tan ^{-1}(u)\log (u)+\frac{i}{2} (\text{Li}_2(i u)-\text{Li}_2(-i u))$$ and use
$$\frac{i}{2} (\text{Li}_2(i u)-\text{Li}_2(-i u))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2 n+1)^2} u^n$$ which has the merit to be alternating.

More compact and exact will be
$$\color{red}{I(t)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\tan ^{-1}(t)\right) \log \left(\tan ^{-1}(t)\right)-\frac{1}{4} \tan ^{-1}(t)\, \Phi \left(-\tan ^{-1}(t)^2,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ where appears the Lerch transcendent function.

Answer (score 1):

Only extended comment.

With CAS help:

$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{p}} \ln (\tan (x)) \, dx=\tan ^{-1}\left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{p}\right)\right) \ln \left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{p}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{2} i \text{Li}_2\left(-i \tan \left(\frac{\pi
   }{p}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2} i \text{Li}_2\left(i \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{p}\right)\right)$

for: $p > 2$, where: $\text{Li}_2(x)$ is  polylogarithm function.

Mathematica code:

`Integrate[Log[Tan[x]], {x, 0, Pi/p}] == ArcTan[Tan[\[Pi]/p]] Log[Tan[\[Pi]/p]] -  1/2 I PolyLog[2, -I Tan[\[Pi]/p]] + 1/2 I PolyLog[2, I Tan[\[Pi]/p]]]`

Comment: Or simpler: $-\frac{1}{2} i \text{Li}_2\left(-i \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{p}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2} i \text{Li}_2\left(i \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{p}\right)\right)+\frac{\pi  \ln \left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{p}\right)\right)}{p}$

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt, however, it does not lead to a nice close form solution. Let $I_{p}$ be defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
I_{p}=\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{p}} \ln(\tan(x))\,dx
\end{equation}

for some real valued $p$ such that $p\geq4$. With the substitution $x=\arctan(t)$, you can transform the integral to the following:

\begin{equation}
I_{p}=\int\limits_{0}^{\tan(\pi/p)} \frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^{2}}\,dt
\end{equation}

Now, by letting $t=e^{-z}$, you will get the following:

\begin{equation}
I_{p}=\int\limits_{\ln(\cot(\pi/p))}^{+\infty} \frac{(-z)e^{-z}}{1+e^{-2z}}\,dz
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_{p}=\int\limits_{\ln(\cot(\pi/p))}^{+\infty} \frac{(-z)e^{-z}}{1-(-e^{-2z})}\,dz
\end{equation}

For simplicity, let $k=\ln(\cot(\pi/p))$. For any $p\geq4$, in the interval $[k,\infty)$, it holds that $0\leq|-e^{-2z}|\leq 1$, so it is justified to use the geometric series. Thus:

\begin{equation}
I_{p}=-\int\limits_{k}^{+\infty} ze^{-z}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-e^{-2z})^{n}\,dz
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_{p}=-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n}\int\limits_{k}^{+\infty} ze^{-z}e^{-2nz}\,dz
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_{p}=-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n}\int\limits_{k}^{+\infty} ze^{-z(1+2n)}\,dz
\end{equation}

By letting $s=z(1+2n)$, we obtain that:

\begin{equation}
I_{p}=-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(1+2n)^{2}}\int\limits_{k(1+2n)}^{+\infty} se^{-s}\,ds
\end{equation}

Using the upper incomplete gamma function, we get the following:

\begin{equation}
I_{p}=-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(1+2n)^{2}}\Gamma(2,k+2nk)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{p}} \ln(\tan(x))\,dx=-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(1+2n)^{2}}\Gamma\left(2,\ln\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{p}\right)\right)+2n\ln\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{p}\right)\right)\right)}
\end{equation}